sending alert in teams for the expiring secrets and certificates
I want to Export app registrations with expiring secrets and certificates and send alert in teams that I can get the expiring apps in the n3xt 30 days with this code in powershell
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Application.Read.All'
$DaysUntilExpiration = 30
$Now = Get-Date
$Logs = @()

Write-Host "Retrieving all applications... This may take a while." -ForegroundColor Yellow
$Applications = Get-MgApplication -all

foreach ($App in $Applications) {
    $AppName = $App.DisplayName
    $AppID   = $App.Id
    $ApplID  = $App.AppId

    $AppCreds = Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId $AppID | Select-Object PasswordCredentials, KeyCredentials
    $Secrets  = $AppCreds.PasswordCredentials
    $Certs    = $AppCreds.KeyCredentials

    foreach ($Secret in $Secrets) {
        $StartDate  = $Secret.StartDateTime
        $EndDate    = $Secret.EndDateTime
        $SecretName = $Secret.DisplayName
        $RemainingDaysCount = ($EndDate - $Now).Days

        if ($RemainingDaysCount -lt 30 -and $RemainingDaysCount -ge 0) {
            $Owner    = Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $App.Id
            $Username = $Owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName -join ';'
            $OwnerID  = $Owner.Id -join ';'

            if ($null -eq $Owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName) {
                $Username = $Owner.AdditionalProperties.displayName + ' **<This is an Application>**'
            }
            if ($null -eq $Owner.AdditionalProperties.displayName) {
                $Username = '<<No Owner>>'
            }

            $Logs += [PSCustomObject]@{
                'ApplicationName'        = $AppName
                'ApplicationID'          = $ApplID
                'Secret Name'            = $SecretName
                'Secret Start Date'      = $StartDate
                'Secret End Date'        = $EndDate
                'ExpiresInDays'          = $RemainingDaysCount
                'Certificate Name'       = $Null
                'Certificate Start Date' = $Null
                'Certificate End Date'   = $Null
                'Owner'                  = $Username
                'Owner_ObjectID'         = $OwnerID
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($Cert in $Certs) {
        $StartDate = $Cert.StartDateTime
        $EndDate   = $Cert.EndDateTime
        $CertName  = $Cert.DisplayName
        $RemainingDaysCount = ($EndDate - $Now).Days

        if ($RemainingDaysCount -lt 30 -and $RemainingDaysCount -ge 0) {
            $Owner    = Get-MgApplicationOwner -ApplicationId $App.Id
            $Username = $Owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName -join ';'
            $OwnerID  = $Owner.Id -join ';'

            if ($null -eq $Owner.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName) {
                $Username = $Owner.AdditionalProperties.displayName + ' **<This is an Application>**'
            }
            if ($null -eq $Owner.AdditionalProperties.displayName) {
                $Username = '<<No Owner>>'
            }
            $Logs += [PSCustomObject]@{
                'ApplicationName'        = $AppName
                'ApplicationID'          = $ApplID
                'Secret Name'            = $Null
                'Certificate Name'       = $CertName
                'Certificate Start Date' = $StartDate
                'Certificate End Date'   = $EndDate
                'ExpiresInDays'          = $RemainingDaysCount
                'Owner'                  = $Username
                'Owner_ObjectID'         = $OwnerID
            }
        }
    }
}

$Logs 

this part works and I want to send alert in teams and I wrote this script for that port


$textTable = $Logs | select-object $AppName, $RemainingDaysCount | ConvertTo-Html
# | Sort-Object daysUntil | select-object displayName, daysUntil | ConvertTo-Html

$JSONBody = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    "@type"      = "MessageCard"
    "@context"   = "<http://schema.org/extensions>"
    "themeColor" = '0078D7'
    "title"      = "$($Array.count) App Secrets areExpiring Soon"
    "text"       = "$textTable"
}

$TeamMessageBody = ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody
$parameters = @{
    "URI"         = 'the URI '
    "Method"      = 'POST'
    "Body"        = $TeamMessageBody
    "ContentType" = 'application/json'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @parameters

but it send alert with empty table in teams even when there are apps that are expiring
can someone help to fix the alert

Change $textTable = $Logs | select-object $AppName, $RemainingDaysCount -> $textTable = $Logs | select-object ApplicationName, ExpiresInDays

Hi @atefehkasiri Any update?

@sridevi with the mentioned change it works

In my case, I used below PowerShell script to send alert in teams with expiring secrets and certificates details:
$header = "Application Name                | Expires In Days"
$separator = "--------------------------------|----------------"

$rows = $Logs | ForEach-Object {
    "{0,-30} | {1, -15}" -f $_.ApplicationName, $_.ExpiresInDays
}

$formattedText = $header + "`n" + $separator + "`n" + ($rows -join "`n")

$JSONBody = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
    "@type"      = "MessageCard"
    "@context"   = "http://schema.org/extensions"
    "themeColor" = '0078D7'
    "title"      = "$($Logs.Count) App Secrets are Expiring Soon"
    "text"       = $formattedText.Trim()
}

$TeamMessageBody = $JSONBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

$parameters = @{
    "URI"         = 'URI'
    "Method"      = 'POST'
    "Body"        = $TeamMessageBody
    "ContentType" = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @parameters

Write-Host "Alert sent successfully." -ForegroundColor Green

Response:

When I checked the same in Teams, alert came successfully with below table:

